# How to add TaskFormatter in YAML config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, celery

I would like to add celery TaskFormatter to my login handlers.
It does work when I configure it in the below code:

```
from celery.app.log import TaskFormatter

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setFormatter(TaskFormatter('%(asctime)s - %(task_id)s - %(task_name)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)
LOGGER.addHandler(sh)
```

But when I try to configure it in the yaml file (I use pyyaml)
I got:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'celery_formatter'
```

My logger.yaml

```
version: 1

formatters:
  celery_formatter:
    class: 'celery.app.log.TaskFormatter'
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(task_id)s - %(task_name)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

handlers:
  stdout_handler:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: celery_formatter
    stream: ext://sys.stdout

loggers:
  app_logger:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file, stdout_handler, stderr_handler]
propagate: no
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details), you can only specify `format` and `datefmt` keys to `formatters` item that will be used to construct `Formatter` instance. It seems that you can't provide a custom formatter class using `class`.

You can however provide `'()'` to provide your custom class, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dict-userdef). The relevant part of you config would then become

```
formatters:
  celery_formatter:
    (): celery.app.log.TaskFormatter
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(task_id)s - %(task_name)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```